# Correspondence subring of algebraic integers - subfield of algebraic numbers

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be the field of algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $R=\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$.

Let $R' \subset R$ be a subring of $R$, and $K' = \langle R' \rangle \subset K$ be the smallest subfield of $K$ containing $R$.

**Question**: Is it true than $R' = \mathcal{O}_{K'}$?

Comment: Can $R'$ be $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Vitor That would not be a problem, as then $K’=\mathbb{Q}$ and it is indeed the case that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Note: the terminology is that $R$ is “the ring of integers of $K$”, or “the ring of algebraic integers in $K$”. When you say “the ring of algebraic integers”, that seems to refer to the subring of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ consisting of all algebraic integers.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Yes $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and  “the ring of integers of K”. I will edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Take $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, so $R=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$. Let $R’=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. Then $K’=K$, but $R’\neq R$.

---

Your $K’$ is the field of fractions of $R’$, so the questions is really equivalent to asking whether $R’$ is integrally closed. Not every subring of an integrally closed ring is integrally closed, though.